# Simplify the following and express in the form $ a + bi$ where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Write $z = \ln(i)$ as $a+bi$, where $i=\sqrt{-1},\, a,b\in\mathbb R$.

Is anybody able to provide me with a hint to lead me in the right direction?

Comment: typo: title should read $i = sqrt(-1)$

Comment: Have you seen Euler's identity? If not there must be some other clue in your textbook. It's not clear how you would do this without some knowledge of the complex exponential.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$i = e^{i\frac{(4k+1)\pi}{2}} \quad \forall k \in \Bbb{Z} $$